# How to plot data in a chronological order while showing numerical labels on the x axis in ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time, x-axis

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame( Time = as.POSIXct(c("2023-08-01 08:00:00", "2023-08-01 12:00:00","2023-08-05 08:00:00", "2023-08-05 12:00:00","2023-08-10 08:00:00", "2023-08-10 12:00:00","2023-08-15 08:00:00", "2023-08-15 12:00:00")),  DAS = c(0, 0, 4, 4, 9, 9, 14, 14), emmean = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45) )
```

I am trying to plot my data in a chronological order (so I need the posixct format I think) while using the numerical DAS values on my x-axis.

```
p<-ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = emmean)) + geom_point()
```

Basically the two options that get the closest results are:

1. `p +  scale_x_continuous(breaks = df$Time,  labels = df$DAS)`
2. `p +  scale_x_datetime(breaks = df$Time,  labels = df$DAS,  date_breaks = "1 day",  date_labels = "%b %d")`

The problem with 1 is that I get the DAS label repeated for each timepoint, which is an issue with my data, as there are way too many points. I want one DAS value for the whole day, not per measurement.
The problem with 2 is that is still shows the date instead of the DAS values.
I would like the break frequency of option 2 with the labeling of option 1.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though `DAS` is the number of days since the first measurement. One option would be to have this explicitly calculated on-the-fly. Simply subtract `min(Time)` from `Time`, which will give you the number of seconds since the first measurement. Convert this to days by dividing by 86400 (the number of seconds in a day)

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.numeric(Time - min(Time))/86400, y = emmean)) + 
 geom_point() +
 xlab('DAS')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks that was exactly what I needed! What is 86400 in this context?

Comment: @Louise it's the number of seconds in a day.